# html dropdown selected value

Tags: javascript, html

I have one dropdown in my html page that contains some 5 values: A, B, C, D, E. When I select C and page refresh, I want to reset all the selected values to the default page. How do I do that? Currently, when I am refreshing the page, the dropdown value is showing the previously selected value. So how do I do that?

Comment: You want dropdown selected value to be reset on page refresh ??

Comment: Which browser are you using? Firefox?

Comment: @user414967 seems forgot to response to your question. Please have a close look to my solution. It may me helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to **body**'s **onload** function and set selected value of the dropdown to desired index.

Answer (score 0):

Add **[autocomplete="off"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)** to your tag so it will not populate fields automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `selected="selected"` attribute to the `<option>` tag, which will make it the default selected drop-down list value, instead of using JavaScript.

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="default" selected="selected">Select A Letter:</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>
</form>​​​
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nR6CP/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this:
<select autocomplete="off">
        <option value="">Select none</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
        <option value="5">E</option>
      </select>
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/nR6CP/2/
```

Comment: @Ismet Alkan please check the update and please inform me if it is working or not..